# SQLite Database showing strange behaviour and malfunctioning other projects as well

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

So i wrote a program to store some data in SQLite. It was second program with SQLIite since am  a beginner. I wrote this:

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase("Name", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (event VARCHAR, year INT(4))");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO events (event, year) VALUES ('Battle of Plassey', 1757)");

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM events", null);

    int eventsIndex = c.getColumnIndex("event");
    int yearIndex = c.getColumnIndex("year");
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (c != null) {
        Log.i("Result - event", c.getString(eventsIndex));
        Log.i("Result - year", Integer.toString(c.getInt(yearIndex)));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Such a simple program but still it's showing some error not only for this program but for every other program i create and run in `Android Studio` .

The error goes something like this:

```
2021-05-30 19:10:20.533 16471-16471/com.learning.sqlitedatabase E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
2021-05-30 19:10:20.566 16471-16471/com.learning.sqlitedatabase W/.sqlitedatabas: DexFile /data/data/com.learning.sqlitedatabase/code_cache/perfa.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
2021-05-30 19:10:21.053 16471-16751/com.learning.sqlitedatabase V/StudioTransport: Agent command stream started.
2021-05-30 19:10:21.054 16471-16750/com.learning.sqlitedatabase V/StudioTransport: Transport agent connected to daemon.
2021-05-30 19:10:21.621 16471-16799/com.learning.sqlitedatabase V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 16471.
2021-05-30 19:10:21.621 16471-16799/com.learning.sqlitedatabase V/StudioTransport: JNIEnv not attached
2021-05-30 19:10:21.897 16471-16799/com.learning.sqlitedatabase V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 16471.
2021-05-30 19:10:21.939 16471-16799/com.learning.sqlitedatabase W/.sqlitedatabas: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2021-05-30 19:10:21.940 16471-16799/com.learning.sqlitedatabase W/.sqlitedatabas: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

The error is very long, i am just showing important bits. It is not just limited to a single project. Creating this database is effecting all the new projects I create in `Android Studio`. And also this same program was running perfectly fine when i ran it a month ago.